# How can be returned input register using only array lower case words in jquery textcomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, utf-8

I use [jquery textcomplete](https://github.com/yuku-t/jquery-textcomplete) in my project. Is it possible to return the input register using a word array only in lowercase. I looked in **Google Translate** the approximate functional and there too the input result does not return at input. There, the search is performed with any word entry register, but will return only in lowercase. How to make it so that when you enter words like `"Stackoveflow"` having words in the words array `['stackoverflow']` returned the result in the input register.

#### Code

```
$('.form-control').textcomplete([{
  words: ['stackoverflow', 'ҳайрат', 'english', 'маҳорат'],
  match: /(^|\S*)([^\u0000-\u007f]{2,}|\w{2,})$/,
  search: function(term, callback) {
    this.words = this.words.map( s => s.toLocaleLowerCase() );
    callback($.map(this.words, function(word) {
      return word.indexOf(term.toLocaleLowerCase()) === 0 ? word : null;
    }));
  },
  index: 2,
  replace: function(word) {
    return word + ' ';
  }
}]);
```

#### Example

How to return the same result when typing while in the array the words will be in the lower case. For example:

Input: `Stackoverflow, STACKOVERFLOW, Ҳайрат, ҲАЙРАТ`

Output: `Stackoverflow, STACKOVERFLOW, Ҳайрат, ҲАЙРАТ`

#### Working code for return input word in lower case

```
$('.form-control').textcomplete([{
  words: ['stackoverflow', 'ҳайрат', 'english', 'маҳорат'],
  match: /(^|\S*)([^\u0000-\u007f]{2,}|\w{2,})$/,
  search: function(term, callback) {
    this.words = this.words.map( s => s.toLocaleLowerCase() );
    callback($.map(this.words, function(word) {
      return word.indexOf(term.toLocaleLowerCase()) === 0 ? word : null;
    }));
  },
  index: 2,
  replace: function(word) {
    return word + ' ';
  }
}]);
```

This code will search typed words in any case but return in lower case from array with words. Example if we type `"English"` end result will be `"english"`. Needed result must be in input case `"English"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand question, this could do the job:

```js
$('#textcomplete').textcomplete([{
  words: ['stackoverflow', 'ҳайрат', 'english', 'маҳорат'],
  match: /(^|\S*)([^\u0000-\u007f]{2,}|\w{2,})$/,
  search: function(term, callback) {
    callback($.map(this.words, function(word) {
      if (word.indexOf(term.toLocaleLowerCase()) !== 0)
        return null;

      if (term[term.length-1] === term[term.length-1].toLocaleUpperCase())
        return word.toLocaleUpperCase(); // last char is upper = uppercase
      if (term[0] === term[0].toLocaleUpperCase())
        return word.charAt(0).toLocaleUpperCase() + word.slice(1); // first char is upper = capitalized
        
      return word; // default; is lowercase
    }));
  },
  index: 2,
  replace: function(word) {
    return word + ' ';
  }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.textcomplete/1.8.4/jquery.textcomplete.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="textcomplete"></textarea>
```

Comment: The word prompt disappears when you enter more than 2 letters in the word. But the result works with the introduction of 2 letters of the word. Can you correct your mistake?

Comment: @John what word did you insert? I cannot reproduce it with english ones..

Comment: When I tried earlier there was an error. But now there seems to be no mistake. Maybe I was wrong. Thank you for your reply and happy new 2018 year. @bigless

Answer (score -1):

> . How to make it so that when you enter words like "Stackoveflow"
>   having words in the words array ['stackoverflow'] returned the result
>   in the input register.

You need to convert all `words` to [localeLowerCase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLocaleLowerCase) first (**in case they are not already**)

```
this.words = this.words.map( s => s.toLocaleLowerCase() );
```

You can put this line just before `callback`

Also, while checking you can convert the `term` to *Locale-Lower-Case* as well.

```
this.words = this.words.map( s => s.toLocaleLowerCase() );
callback($.map(this.words, function(word) {
  return word.indexOf(term.toLocaleLowerCase()) === 0 ? word : null;
}));
```

Comment: Thanks! What will be the complete code? @gurvinder372

Comment: In general, I tried your solution but it does not save the input case of letters. Return the result as it exists on the word array. @gurvinder372

Comment: @john can you share a working fiddle or a snippet so that your issue can be replicated?